# show/hide one Textbox/Label in Gridview based on condition in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have gridview and I would like to show/hide one of them based on condition in code behind

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="Q1TB" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:label ID="Q1LB"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q1") %>'></asp:label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Tried many things but with no sucess

Edit:

Tried in RowDataBound

```
e.Row.FindControl("Q1TB").Visible = False
```

got Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

Also tried changing the style to display to non got error

```
e.Row.FindControl("Q1TB").Style.Add("display", "none")
```

Style is not a member of style.web.ui.control

Comment: have you try to hide items on `GridView RowDataBound` event ? can you update the question with the code you already tried ?

Comment: Bit of code, error, line it falls over on etc. would be helpful.

Comment: Before finding control check for `e.Row.RowType`, `if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){/*Your code*/}`

Comment: [RowDatabound event tips and tricks in Gridview contro](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource17-RowDatabound-event-tips-and-tricks-in-Gridview-control.aspx)

Comment: whats your condition to show / hide them?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Design Page:**

```
<GridView ID="MyGridView" OnDataBound="GridView_DataBound">
```

**Code-Behind:-**

```
protected void GridView_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    if (Set condition here)
    {
        MyGridView.Columns[1].Visible = false;
        MyGridView.Columns[2].Visible = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Need to check for `RowType` also.

Comment: I beleive this hide/shows columns where I would like to hide  one of the textbox/label from the same row/col

Answer (score 0):

Try this in databound :

```
TextBox  tempText = e.Item.FindControl("Q1TB") as TextBox;
tempTex.Visible = False;
```

Answer (score 0):

if the purpose is to show or hide a part of the page then you can do the following things

1) wrap it in markup with

```
<% if(somecondition) { %>
   some html
<% } %>


<ItemTemplate>
<%
if(condition)
    {%>

<asp:TextBox ID="Q1TB" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q1") %>'></asp:TextBox>



   <% } 
else 
{
%>

<asp:label ID="Q1LB"  runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Q1") %>'></asp:label>
<% } %>



</ItemTemplate>
```